# group_concat and SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

Tags: sql, magento

On the sales order admin page in Magento I sometimes (though not always) get an error on the page, and see in `var/report`:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `m_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`

INNER JOIN `m_sales_flat_order_item` 
ON `m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id

INNER JOIN `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
ON (m_catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id`) 
AND `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id=163 
WHERE (`m_sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL) 
AND ((group_concat(`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.value SEPARATOR ', ') like '%tenzen%'))
```

Can anyone shed light on why this happens and how I could fix it?

Comment: Aggregate function conditions should be in HAVING clause, not in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the query is the `group_concat()` in the `where` clause.  However, you don't need `group_concat()` at all for this logic.

However, you do need to aggregate to bring all the rows for a given entity together.  This requires a subquery, so I would suggest rewriting it as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT main_table.entity_id
      FROM `m_sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN 
           `m_sales_flat_order_item` 
           ON `m_sales_flat_order_item`.order_id = `main_table`.entity_id INNER JOIN 
           `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar` 
           ON m_catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = `m_sales_flat_order_item`.`product_id` AND 
             `m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.attribute_id = 163 
      WHERE `m_sales_flat_order_item`.parent_item_id IS NULL
      GROUP BY main_table.entity_id
      HAVING SUM(`m_catalog_product_entity_varchar`.value like '%tenzen%') > 0
     ) t
```